# Cannot generate json class

Tags: c#, json

I have this `json`:

```
{
    "home": {
        "0_15": {
            "goals": 7,
            "percentage": 14
        },
        "15_30": {
            "goals": 6,
            "percentage": 12
        },
        "30_45": {
            "goals": 11,
            "percentage": 22
        },
        "45_60": {
            "goals": 4,
            "percentage": 8
        },
        "60_75": {
            "goals": 8,
            "percentage": 16
        },
        "75_90": {
            "goals": 14,
            "percentage": 28
        }
    },
    "away": {
        "0_15": {
            "goals": 7,
            "percentage": 15.56
        },
        "15_30": {
            "goals": 7,
            "percentage": 15.56
        },
        "30_45": {
            "goals": 5,
            "percentage": 11.11
        },
        "45_60": {
            "goals": 6,
            "percentage": 13.33
        },
        "60_75": {
            "goals": 13,
            "percentage": 28.89
        },
        "75_90": {
            "goals": 7,
            "percentage": 15.56
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to generate the class using [this](http://json2csharp.com/) tool. When I paste on that tool it say:

> Parsing your JSON didn't work. Please make sure it's valid.

So I tried to check if this json is valid using [this](https://jsonlint.com/) tool, and the json is valid, so why I cannot generate the c# class?

Comment: That is a problem with the tool. We would have no knowledge of why that tool does not work.

Comment: @Nkosi ok so, you confirm that my json is valid?

Comment: Try [this](https://app.quicktype.io/) tool.

Comment: @popop well apart from the fact that c# class name cannot start or be only digits

Comment: okay, maybe the tool cannot elaborate such design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If** you're parsing the `JSON` at runtime I recommend using `NewtonSoft` nuget package.  It's amazing and probably the most used.

**If** you want to copy and paste `JSON` and make a class I recommend using **Visual Studio** to do this.

Just copy the `JSON` normally like a copy paste, open a class (or make a new class) in Visual Studio, then select

> Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON as Classes

and it will turn it into the C# classes needed for you.

Your `JSON` above results in the following (that you can edit and modify as needed.)

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Home home { get; set; }
    public Away away { get; set; }
}

public class Home
{
    public _0_15 _0_15 { get; set; }
    public _15_30 _15_30 { get; set; }
    public _30_45 _30_45 { get; set; }
    public _45_60 _45_60 { get; set; }
    public _60_75 _60_75 { get; set; }
    public _75_90 _75_90 { get; set; }
}

public class _0_15
{
    public int goals { get; set; }
    public int percentage { get; set; }
}

public class _15_30
{
    public int goals { get; set; }
    public int percentage { get; set; }
}

public class _30_45
{
    public int goals { get; set; }
    public int percentage { get; set; }
}

public class _45_60
{
    public int goals { get; set; }
    public int percentage { get; set; }
}

public class _60_75
{
    public int goals { get; set; }
    public int percentage { get; set; }
}

public class _75_90
{
    public int goals { get; set; }
    public int percentage { get; set; }
}

public class Away
{
    public _0_151 _0_15 { get; set; }
    public _15_301 _15_30 { get; set; }
    public _30_451 _30_45 { get; set; }
    public _45_601 _45_60 { get; set; }
    public _60_751 _60_75 { get; set; }
    public _75_901 _75_90 { get; set; }
}

public class _0_151
{
    public int goals { get; set; }
    public float percentage { get; set; }
}

public class _15_301
{
    public int goals { get; set; }
    public float percentage { get; set; }
}

public class _30_451
{
    public int goals { get; set; }
    public float percentage { get; set; }
}

public class _45_601
{
    public int goals { get; set; }
    public float percentage { get; set; }
}

public class _60_751
{
    public int goals { get; set; }
    public float percentage { get; set; }
}

public class _75_901
{
    public int goals { get; set; }
    public float percentage { get; set; }
}
```

**Image**

[image]

Comment: whoa, I didn't know that! Thanks!

Comment: @popop  I didn't either until about a year ago; a coworker showed me and I was thinking, "Why haven't I ever seen this before?"